# Excel 2010 Recordset - How to insert a sequential number into an extracted ODBC recordset based on unique identifer

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

ColumnA    ColumnB
EnquiryNo    VisitNo
1804          0 
1804        0
1804          0
1805          0
1806          0
1807          0
1807        0

Hope you can help as I am stumped!

My excel spreadsheet has 2 columns. Column A has been extracted through ODBC. I want Column B to increment by 1 each time Column A duplicates an Enquiry Number so it would look like this...

ColumnA     ColumnB
EnquiryNo     VisitNo
1804          1 
1804        2
1804          3
1805          1
1806          1
1807          1
1807          2

This is live data through an ODBC connection so the code needs to search for the Enquiry Number first, do a count of the number of instances of the enquiry number and then determine the next number in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an adjacent formula  like the following.

The formula in C2 is what is entered in B2
The key is the formula having a fixed starting range value and an adjusting end range end value

[image]